# EJS ERROR: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, ejs

I was using handlebars (hbs) before now I'm switching 'hbs' to 'ejs'. I'm getting this error !!
I'm new to ejs . I'm trying  to display the specific users files on the dashboard.
What am I doing wrong?
Please help me !!

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\views\dashboard.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12)
    at Object.compile (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
    at handleCache (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at E:\EXP_NP\ALPHA\routes\users.js:43:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Dashboard EJS code: *(views/dashboard.ejs)*
**dashboard.ejs**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #222;">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white hsize" href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a href="logout" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-md" role="button">LOGOUT</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <h1>Welcome <%= name %></h1>
        <div class="btable">
            <a href="/files/add" class="btn btn-outline-dark" role="button"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add
                Files</a>
            <input type="text" class="field small-field" style="flex-grow: 0.5;" />
            <input type="submit" class="button btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" value="Search" />
        </div>
<% if(files) { %>
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="1">TITLE</th>
                <th width="400">CREATED AT</th>
                <th width="120">EDIT FILES</th>
                <th width="100">DELETE FILES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/files/<%- _id %>"></a><%= title %></td>
            <td><%= formatDate createdAt 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' %></td>
            <td>
                <a href="/files/edit/<%- _id %>" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-float">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="/files/<%- _id %>" method="POST" id="delete-form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
                         <i class="fas fa-trash "></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <% }); %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<% } else { %>
    <p class="m-2">You have not created any files</p>
    <p class="m-2">Click Add Files to create new files</p>
<% } %>
```

ROUTER CODE: *(routes/user.js)*
**users.js**

```
// @desc    Dashboard
// @route   GET /users/dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const files = await File.find({user: req.user.id }).lean()

        res.render('dashboard', {
            layout: 'dashboard',
            title: 'Dashboard',
            name: req.user.name,
            files
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/500')
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

The second `<td>` tag

```html
<td><%= formatDate createdAt 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' %></td>
```

is not executing your `formatDate()` function and passing those arguments correctly.

#### Potential Solution

`formatDate()` needs to be executed properly as you would in a regular javascript file, and you also need to reference the `_id`, `title`, and the `createdAt` values from each `item` you're mapping through.

The code below sort of demonstrates what you should be going for

```html
<tbody>
    <% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/files/<%- item._id %>"></a><%= item.title %></td>
    <td><%= formatDate(item.createdAt, 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') %></td>
    <td>
        <a href="/files/edit/<%- item._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-float">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="/files/<%- item._id %>" method="POST" id="delete-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
                 <i class="fas fa-trash "></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

**NB:** The `formatDate()` function should be available in the scope of that for it to be called otherwise it'll result in an `undefined`.

Here's an [ejs playground tool](https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/) for further tinkering